# successful MYSQL query not showing in Database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Following the instructions in my book, I altered my table twice. Both queries were reported as successful in the terminal. However, when I double check PHP MYAdmin the 'FK_project_user' doesn't show up. However, FK_user_project query does show up in database.

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the intent of the SQL or if there's some problem. I deleted the table and redid the whole process over again and got same result.

Can anyone explain?

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `tbl_project_user_assignment` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_project_user` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_project` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.21 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE `tbl_project_user_assignment` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_user_project` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

[image: database]

Comment: I'd not use cascaded delete, but that's a different issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after the query and then look for the user. I am not sure if it will work. FLUSH PRIVILEGES tells the mysql server to reload it's privilege information from the tables in the 'mysql' database.

Comment: thanks. I'm a bit of a newbie. Can you provide a bit more detail. Do I redo the query and write FLUSH PRIVILEGES at the end? If not how?

Comment: After you run your query run the second query 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;'. Infact I too am a newbie for mysql and mostly use the ORM layer to interact with mysql... ;)  Just trying to help :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn{t run the query again. I just put in FLUSH PRIVILEGES; and it said Query OK zero rows affected. but the database is the same

Comment: We have to use it for the user and privileges to take effect when we create a new user and grant privileges on some database. I think you should run it soon after you create the user `FK_project_user` and grant privileges to it. After that run the ALTER TABLE query. See if it works. If it doesn't then run FLUSH PRIVILEGES in the end also.
If it is not helping then there may be some other problem.